# how to return json response from views.py instead of .html file in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on django project that is returning a template in its views.py with context as:
return render_to_response('page.html', context)
here context is a dictionary that is having keys and values from multiple model classes

I need to just return the json response instead of html page. please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a view that returns a [**`JsonResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'some_key': 'some_value'})
```

> (…) is a dictionary that is having keys and values from multiple model classes

You can simply pass model objects as JSON. In that case you need to *serialize* this properly. You can use [Django's serialization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/), or work with a [**`Serializer`** from the Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). The Django REST framework also offers a lot of tooling for CRUD operations with JSON or XML, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects if you're only using Django.

But If you use drf you could use drf Response's.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/